# Fix 2 user performing same action at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into a scalability issue where a User can connect to a store. However that store can only be connect to one User.

The issue now is that multiple User are clicking "connect" at the exact same time, and that messes it up.

I put it in a background job that runs this with Sidekiq:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  store = Store.find_by(guid: guid)
  return unless store
  store.connect!
end
```

I thought that this would solve the issue of never allowing 2 of these actions to be performed at the same time, I guess they should be queued in a way.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

in a database setup you would use a database lock. rails offers support for optimistic and pessimistic locking. i think that this article summarizes the usage and tradeoffs quite well for beginners http://thelazylog.com/understanding-locking-in-rails-activerecord/